# Missing auto generated id in django model

Tags: python, django

I have a class and I skipped the `id` autogenerated definition because Django is suposed to do it for you.

When I instantiate `myClass` and save a record I have this:

```
instance = Cotization(value1, value2, value3, value4, value5)
instance.save()
```

It gives me an error on value 3.

I saw that if instead of the 3 values I add an integer at the start it will be added and the starting value is the ID.

I dont understand what I am doing wrong, from the admin interface I can add records with no problems.

the error i got is

> jango.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed:
>   ah_cotizacion.Product,

but the thing is not in the value, if i just add a valid integer at the start it will add the record proprtl

EDIT: My models

```
# Create your models here.
class Producto(models.Model):

    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    id =  models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    umbral = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre




class Cotizacion(models.Model):


    minimo = models.FloatField()
    maximo = models.FloatField()
    promedio = models.FloatField()
    cantidad = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    Producto = models.ForeignKey(Producto)

    def __str__(self):

        return self.Producto.nombre
```

The script I am tring to make work is this:

```
def registrarCotizacionProducto(producto):

    with open('resultados/temporal.json') as json_data:
        d = json.load(json_data)
        resultadoX = b.buscarObjeto(d, producto.id)


        cantidad = resultadoX['cantidad']
        maximo = round(resultadoX['maximo'], 2)
        minimo = round(resultadoX['minimo'], 2)
        promedio = round(resultadoX['promedio'], 2)

    cot = Cotizacion(minimo, maximo, promedio, cantidad, producto.id)
    cot.save()
```

Comment: What error do you get with `value3`?

Comment: jango.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: ah_cotizacion.Product, but the thing is not in the value, if i just add a valid integer at the start it will add the record proprtly

Comment: The last value has to be an id for a foreign Key, the class is defined wit only 3 values, 2 normal integeres and the 3rd is a foreign key (also integer)

Comment: You should copy the error into your question. It's pretty much impossible to help you without seeing the model/error.

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the problem itself

Comment: You should not reuse the name `Producto` for the attribute. It might cause weired side effects in the `Cotizacion` class.

Comment: What are the values of `value1`, `value2`, etc.?

Comment: @Alexev The error has everything to do with the problem. Having an error is a problem, and so that's the first step into figuring out what's going on. Also, as per your comment on wpercy's answer – you should always provide the minimal code to reproduce the problem. If the code you're using and the code you're showing us is different, it's much more difficult for someone to help you, as the problem may not even be reproducible. Further, it's not really possible to understand what's going on if we can't see the relevant code/error(s).

Comment: You are right, there is all the code in the question now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the feedback and the time+effort.

At last after a lot of try-error I found the solution

It seems that even if you have an autogenerated id that is not part of your model you have to pass it by parameter anyway, and as like normal SQL it can be done by passing a NULL value or the Python equivalent `None`

So, the answer is

```
Rose = Producto.objects.get(id=124105)
cot = Cotizacion(None, 13, 141, 15, Rose)
cot.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the `ForeignKey` field does not allow null values by default, but you're trying to initialize an instance of the Cotizacion class without a reference to any Producto instance.

Comment: I have a producto instance, I just didnt put that in the code example.

Comment: Well put it in the example

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to initialize Cotization with three arguments where definition of this model expects five of them.

Are we talking still about Cotization or maybe Producto?

Update (after original post was updated about additional data):
Please take a look on [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/optimization/#use-foreign-key-values-directly). Please use underscore character or just full object. "dot" notation is same optimal as giving full object.

```
cot = Cotizacion(minimo, maximo, promedio, cantidad, producto_id)
```

or

```
cot = Cotizacion(minimo, maximo, promedio, cantidad, producto)
```

Comment: Your link seems to be a great idea, I will try that at home because it also seems to correct other problem I got